# zeppelin "r interpreter not found"

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I have [installed](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.0-incubating/install/install.html) local `apache zeppelin` using this [link](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.0-incubating/install/install.html)
The examples in that very same installation show usage of `r` but when i run any of them i get: `"r interpreter not found"`.  This is very strange the same installation which shows example notebook of "R Notebook" does not contain a zeppelin interpreter!!? when i click the `"Interpreters"` tab I do not see any `r` interpreter.  I saw there is a project [zeppelin with r](https://github.com/elbamos/Zeppelin-With-R) but i don't get it.  How come the very same `zeppelin` installation which has `r` notebook examples does not work? why do I need to clone a repository named `Zeppelin With R`? isn't `R` bundled already with `zeppelin`??

Comment: Do you see R interpreter on [the list](https://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.0-incubating/docs.html)? I am pretty sure it should answer your question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2016 Apr 6th Apache Zeppelin [has R support in master branch](https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/blob/master/docs/interpreter/r.md).

It's not part of the [latest 0.5.6](http://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.5.6-incubating/) release, so you need to build Zeppelin following this very simple [build instructions](https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin/blob/master/docs/interpreter/r.md)

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin.git
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

Here you can find more information about pre-requests for [R and rSpark support available](http://zeppelin.incubator.apache.org/docs/0.6.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT/interpreter/r.html)

> Additional requirements for the R interpreter are:
>
> - R 3.1 or later (earlier versions may work, but have not been tested)
> - The evaluate R package.
> - etc

Answer (score 3):

R support is not bundled in the binary by default.

It can be compiled in few steps

```
git clone https://github.com/apache/zeppelin.git
cd zeppelin
mvn clean package -Pr -DskipTests
# or using another R support with 
# mvn clean package -Psparkr -DskipTests
```

The R tutorial comes together with the binary is a snapshot of the notebook include the execution result/graph.

Comment: I did same steps based on your comment. But I can't use the R interpreter. When I type the '%r' then 'Interpreter r not found'. Is there anything else behind what I have to do?